# Is the intersection of multiple circles that all intersect a specific point always convex?

Tags: convex-analysis, circles

Assuming I have some circles whose mutual intersection area is > 0, and each of the circles' edges intersect the same point, e.g. as shown in this picture:

[image]

Will the mutual intersection set (edge + interior) always convex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Circles are convex and the intersection of convex sets is again convex, so yes.](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Convexity/The_intersection_of_convex_sets_is_convex)
In fact it doesn't matter if the area is nonzero or if the edges match up nicely, it's always true regardless since circles are convex.

Comment: A little terminology issue : it would be more adequate to use the word "disk", and preserve the name "circle" for the boundary of these "disks"